# Check SQL entry from GET input method

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I can't make my code work like I want it to.

```
$Check = $_POST['phrase'];

    try{ $db=new readPDO('testDB'); $sql=('

        SELECT entry, ID
        FROM test
        WHERE entry = "$Check "

        ');

$statement=$db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

If I try this:

```
$Check = $_POST['phrase'];

    try{ $db=new readPDO('testDB'); $sql=('

        SELECT entry, ID
        FROM test
        WHERE ID= "$Check "

        ');

$statement=$db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

The GET is a number which works fine, but it doesn't work with strings.

Comment: Try reversing your quotes

Comment: Or use [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Comment: You say `GET` input, *yet* you're using `$Check = $_POST['phrase'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> A [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) literal can be specified in four different ways:
>
> - [single quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)
> - [double quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)
> - [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)
> - [nowdoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) (since PHP 5.3.0)
>
> #### Single quoted
>
> The simplest way to specify a [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) is to enclose it in single quotes (the character ').
>
> > **Note**: Unlike the [double-quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) and [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntaxes, [variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) and escape sequences for special characters will *not* be expanded when they occur in single quoted [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)s.
>
> ```
> <?
> // [ deletia ]
>
> // Outputs: Variables do not $expand $either
> echo 'Variables do not $expand $either';
> ?>
> ```
>
> #### Double quoted
>
> If the [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters:
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> The most important feature of double-quoted [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)s is the fact that variable names will be expanded. See [string parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for details.

In your case, `$sql` is assigned the value of a **single-quoted string literal** in which the `$Check` variable will not be expanded (whilst it is itself enclosed by double-quotes therein, so far as the PHP parser is concerned it is still a single-quoted string literal).

Using a double-quoted string literal would provide variable expansion.  If you still wish to quote `$Check` within the string literal using double-quotes, then they would have to be escaped (with backslashes):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT entry, ID
    FROM test
    WHERE entry = \"$Check \"
";
```

Alternatively, one could now quote `$Check` using single quotes (since [MySQL recognises both forms of string quoting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html), provided that [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) is disabled):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT entry, ID
    FROM test
    WHERE entry = '$Check '
";
```

Note that the trailing space within the quotes will be parsed by MySQL as part of the string, which may not be your intention.

Note also that **this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks** (and also bugs if `$Check` happens to contain certain characters).  You should read [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)'s blog article [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) to understand this better; and then [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496) to understand how to fix it.